# Are airflow monthly dags delayed by a day or a month?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to set an airflow dag that runs on second day of each month. Based on my research, the schedule interval should be set to:

```
schedule_interval = '0 0 2 * *'
```

Now what worries my is the stuff discussed in [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html). Based on what's discussed there:

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run
> stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In
> other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has
> ended.
>
> Let’s Repeat That The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval
> AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Does this mean that for monthly dags, everything will be delayed by one month? So for example the `2020-11-02` job will run on `2020-12-01 2359`? If yes, how can I make sure that it runs exactly when it's supposed to?

Answer (score 3):

Your interpretion is right, the DAG Run with `execution_date=2020-11-02` will be triggered approximately on `2020-12-01 23:59`. However, I think you don't need to be worried that the DAG is delayed or something, it still has a monthly schedule and will run every month. You rather need to take this logic into account when running a operator.

You can also simply work with [other variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref) if you don't want to adapt the logic, for whatever reason:

> **{{ next_execution_date }}** - the next execution date.